# Error in using Recycler View and Scroll View together?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have been facing issue using Recycler View and Scroll View together in the same bottom navigation activity in different tabs. I am hiding one of the view by using Visibility Gone in the java file.

I tried many solutions but nothing worked till now so I am posting here if someone can help me figure it out.

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.cartoonswikipedia.www.familyconnect.Main2Activity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/postrecycler"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="312dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileimagee45"
            android:layout_width="69dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="hi"
            android:padding="12dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/c" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editemail"
            android:layout_width="262dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.113" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileimage"
            android:layout_width="87dp"
            android:layout_height="88dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:onClick="proimg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.167"
            android:clickable="false"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editname"
            android:layout_width="262dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.338" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/abcdef"
            android:orientation="vertical">
               <RelativeLayout
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/children"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Children"
                android:textSize="25dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/adddd"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editheight"
            android:layout_width="262dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Height in CM"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.338" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editweight"
            android:layout_width="262dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Weight in KG"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.338" />
        <RelativeLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/blood"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
                android:text="Blood Group"
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/religion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
                android:text="Religion"
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editprofile"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:onClick="edit"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Save Profile"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:onClick="logout"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Log Out"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/empty_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.473"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.464" />


    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Comment: Scrollview can have only one Child element.And show us the Error.

Comment: @meditat error is that only the scroll view works in one of the tab and the recycler view doesn't work in other tab.

Comment: @meditat I use Visibility.GONE to hide the scroll view and recycler view to switch between the tabs. Is it fine?

Comment: Did you try disabling scroll in `RecyclerView` when `ScrollView` is in use?

Comment: try to use use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`